# Why Fatfreeframework (F3) keep give me "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed" message, even when I have correct Class->method to process the POST|GET request?

Tags: fat-free-framework, http-status-code-405

I've been trying to solve this strange problem. I just want to redirect a request to do a specific function using POST|GET method.
At first, I thought this was a straightforward scenario, but I found it little bit challenging.

I have this in my routing configuration (for GET method) :

```
    [routes]
    GET /pub/adsprocess/@command/@adsid=AdsController->processAds
```

and the code in my "view" file :

```
       < a href="/pub/adsprocess/yes/1" >YES </a>
       < a href="/pub/adsprocess/no/2" >NO </a>
```

My controller look like this :

```
    class AdsController extends Controller
    {
        function processAds()
        {
            $command = $this->f3->get('PARAMS.command');
            $ads_id = $this->f3->get('PARAMS.adsid');

            /*some more process here...*/
        }    
    }
```

As far as I see, everything looks ok to me. But, all of this doesn't work, F3 keep showing me "**Method Not Allowed HTTP 405**" error message. And this error message stay there when I use POST method, too.

I'm not sure where to look. Any clue or alternative approach to this problem will highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sigit

Comment: can you show the url you use to access this link?

Comment: Is the controller namespaced?
Also consider spacing
`GET /pub/adsprocess/@command/@adsid = AdsController->processAds`

Comment: @Daniel : here is the url  http://retail.localhost/pub/adsprocess/yes/1

Comment: @GeoffreyMureithi : No, I don't use namespace, and there are other functions under this controller that work perfectly fine. About adding space, yes, I tried that before for the sake of curiosity, but it seems it has nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: which version do you use and do you have similar other routes? Maybe another controller fetched this request where the actual method is not present.

Comment: @ikkez : Hi, I'm using version 3.5. I already double check and I'm pretty sure all controllers fetch their proper method.

Comment: @dewa19 can you dump the HTTP response headers? That should help understand where that 405 comes from.

Comment: More specifically, the `X-Powered-By` and `Allow` headers.

Comment: You've said you have other functions under this controller that work, but are there more routing rules in this config file that work? Maybe it's the config file that doesn't get loaded?

Comment: @dewa19 Sounds like a server setup issue to me. if you increase the DEBUG value in your config.ini to 3 or more, you should get more info.

Answer (score 0):

as i can't comment, can we see the autoloader variable? I mean, if you place the `AdsController` in a Controller Folder and you didn't add the controller folder to the autoloader, then you need to access it like this:

`\Controller\AdsController->processAds`

and the `AdsController.php` file must be added the namespace to works:

```php
Namespace Controller;
class AdsController extends \Controller
{
    function processAds()
    {
        $command = $this->f3->get('PARAMS.command');
        $ads_id = $this->f3->get('PARAMS.adsid');

        /*some more process here...*/
    }    
}
```

if you **did** add it to the autoloader variable, it's should be work on your way.

Comment: In my case was a forgotten comma at the end of the "ini" route.